# How to resolve OutOfMemory:Java HeapSpace on my Client Program (with Eclipse)

Tags: java, client-server, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am writing a client-server program. The client is on another computer on the same WLAN. The problem I am confronted with is this exception on the client side: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

The problem is that if I use the server computer as the client too (Server-Client on the same machine), it does not throw this exception. However, every time I run the client from another computer to download a document, it throws the exception.

Kindly help with an easy way to go about this. I use Eclipse.

Below is my client class:

```
public void run() {
     try {
            servsock = new ServerSocket(13330);

        while (true) {
          System.out.println("Waiting on question server...");
          try {
          sock = servsock.accept();
          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
          // receive file
          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
          InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
          String LocalLocation = "C:\\NewEvalve\\LocalUploadedFiles\\"+clasx+"\\"+subject+"\\"+filename;
            File LocalFile = new File(LocalLocation);

            File file = new File("C:\\NewEvalve\\LocalUploadedFiles\\"+clasx+"\\"+subject);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                new File("C:\\NewEvalve\\LocalUploadedFiles\\"+clasx+"\\"+subject).mkdirs();
                System.out.println(file+ " now exists.");
                }
          File outputfile = new File("C:\\NewEvalve\\LocalUploadedFiles\\"+clasx+"\\"+subject+"\\"+filename);
          fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
          bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
          bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
          current = bytesRead;

          do {
             bytesRead =
                is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
             if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
          } while(bytesRead > -1);

          bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
          bos.flush();
          System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED
              + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
        }
        finally {
          if (fos != null) fos.close();
          if (bos != null) bos.close();
          if (sock != null) sock.close();
        } }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

...... and here is my server class that uploads the file:

```
public void uploadIt(InetAddress retur2, String fileLocation2){
    try{
    File myFile = new File (fileLocation2);
    sock = new Socket(retur2, 13330);
    System.out.println("Connection on "+sock.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    os = sock.getOutputStream();
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    System.out.println("Sent " + fileLocation2 + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  finally {
    try {
      if (bis != null)bis.close();
    if (os != null) os.close();
    if (sock!=null) sock.close();
    System.out.println("Completed Upload");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

}
```

Comment: You `fis,bis,os,fos,bos` closing doesn't look healthy... You should first of all send some time to clean that mess a bit.

Comment: Which types of file you are reading (binary, text, etc) ?

Comment: I am reading short videos, audios, and text based files - maximum of all can't be more than 100MB each (at worst). I need help with how to read files in small chunks _ can anyone please help with a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *reading text file* then you should use **BufferedReader & BufferedWriter** instead of reading whole file at a time, like this

```
File file = new File("your file");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file"));
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    bw.write(currentLine);
}
bw.close();
br.close();
```

If you are *reading binary files* then it is suggested to use **BufferedInputStream & BufferedOutputStream**. You **cannot read binary data using BufferedReader** because **it convert binary data into string format & your file will corrupt or damaged.**

*It may be possible there is no line terminator in your file. In that case, reader continues reading file until there is space in heap memory.* Thats why you get **OutOfMemory** error.

---

**EDIT :**

To perform read/write operations on **Audio Files** there is an extension available in **Java Standard Edition - Sound**. You can use classes in **javax.sound.sampled.*** package.

Example for Audio File :

```
File fileIn = new File("your file");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
// do something
File fileOut = new File("new file");
if (AudioSystem.isFileTypeSupported(AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioInputStream)) {
    AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, fileOut);
}
```

To get detailed idea on sound package look at this [Java Sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html)

---

To work with **video file format** you can do like below :-

There is method in Java `getResourceAsStream("your video file")` which returns an object of InputStream. This stream you can use to read video file data & write it to another file or whatever you want to do.

[InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) - Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) Some sample code will look like this :-

```
try {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("your video file");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    BufferedOutputStream bus = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                                       new File("your new video file")));
    byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
    int read = in.read(data);
    bus.write(read);
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

Comment: There is a point! I am using the code to read Videos, Audio, Text Files and such... This probably means I should read each type of file separately. I do agree, I should read it bit by bit too...

Comment: If this answer helps you to solve your error, then you should accept it.

Comment: What way is best to read Audio and Video files? What form of read and writing stream can I use?

Comment: @Jojo I have updated my answer with the solutions to perform read & write operations on audio & video files. I hope this will help you more. Have a look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Practically you can just adjust the maximum amount of memory your VM is going to use. Just use `-Xmx<size>` parameter to adjust this. For example `-Xmx512m` is going to use maximum of 512 MB of memory.

I've also noticed that you're reading a file as a big chunk into memory. I would do it piece by piece (like pieces of 1 or 2 kb) in order to prevent huge instant memory demands.

Answer (score 0):

HotSpot sizes its heap according to the total physical RAM on a machine. When you change host machines, you implicitly change the heap limits. It would seem that, on your remote machine, you have less RAM, therefore you hit the limit.

However, the real advice would be not to load the entire file into memory; instead read the file in chunks and write them directly to the network socket. Then you won't face this issue no matter what the file size. The same reasoning applies to the server side as well: do not read the whole file from the socket into RAM, but dump it directly into a file.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't know how to go about reading the files in chunks, I am uploading, short videos, audios, text based documents, Can you help me with a way of doing it? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try to raise perm space, add following parameters to vm start-up

**-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

also add **-XX:MaxPermSize=256m** `to Tomcat in Eclipse: Server > Open Launch Configuration > Arguments`

Reference link is here : [Out of memory](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/)